# Prolog - Describe facts and rules

Tags: prolog

I want to describe in prolog the following facts and rules:

1. Nick is programming in Java.
2. Nick is programming in Python
3. Nick is friend with anyone that is programming in Java and Python
4. Jim is programming in all languages that Nick does.

I found the solution for 1, 2 and 3 but not for the 4th, even though i would really appreciate a full solution.

**My solution:**

```
male(Nick).

male(Jim).

programming(Nick, java).

programming(Nick, python).

friends(X,Y):-
    programming(X,java),
    programming(X,python),
    programming(Y,java),
    programming(Y,python),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few errors in your solution:

- A constant (like `Nick`) starting with a *capital letter* is no constant; but a variable. Thus the line:

  ```
  male(Nick).
  ```

  says that everyone is a `male/1`; you should correct it to:

  ```
  male(nick).
  male(jim).
  ```

  (the same for `programming/2` by the way).
  furthermore this doesn't seem to be part of the assignment (?).
- The `friends/2` predicate ends with a comma (`,`) meaning that the Prolog parser expects more input, and will see the next fact as part of the current clause; you should end clauses with the dot (`.`);
- The `friends/2` predicate is not semantically correct, since the question only makes statements about Nick: you thus can't use `X` as the person, you should specialize it like:

  ```
  friends(nick,Y):-
      programming(Y,java),
      programming(Y,python).
  ```

  Your version of `friends/2` said: *"A person X is a friend of a person Y, if both X and Y can program in Java and Python"*; although this results in the fact that Nick is a friend of everyone that programs in Java and Python, your statements is broader than what should be allowed: we don't know if Jim for instance decides who is friends with him based on these rules. It is for instance possible (although perhaps not likely) that Jim wants to learn things from his friends, and for instance is only friends with people that know at least one programming language he doesn't master.
- The last question can be written as:

  ```
  programming(jim,X) :-
      programming(nick,X).
  ```

  an almost mechanical translation of the statement is: *"Jim is programming in X **if** nick is programming in X"*; (mind this is no *if-and-only-if*); so you can still add additional languages Jim can work with.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used Capital Letter by mistake, and the comma was there because of "copy-paste". So by correcting the mistakes and adding the last part of code i am answering to all 4 questions right?