# Prolog Rules (Predicates)

Tags: prolog

I'm new in Prolog SWI can you help me to solve this.
Suppose have a database with predicates likes (person1, person2) and hobbies (person1, hobby). Now, how can I design a rule such that the system answers that two people have the same kind of liking or not depending on their hobbies.

```
likes (john, jake).  
true
```

Comment: Write the rule in normal language first, without regard to Prolog. What would it be? What does it mean to have the "same kind of liking depending on their hobbies"? Do you mean a rule that determines if two people simply have the same hobby? Or are you looking for a rule that defines two people who both like each other *and* have the same hobby? Is your "like" fact one directional? (if a likes b, is it also implicitly true that b likes a?)

Comment: its mean that two people simply have the same hobby that's it.

Comment: So write a rule, `A likes B iff A has a hobby H and B has a hobby H`.

Comment: i tried something like this 
 checkhobby(A,B) :-
            likes(A,H),
            likes(B,H),
            dif(A,B).

Comment: but I don't know how can i test it with DB?

Comment: This rule seem to use different names from the question.

Comment: yeah I know that's why I'm not getting that! there is two functions in Qs how can I use them on this problem

Comment: Of interest: [Prolog - Describe facts and rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32685993/1243762)

Comment: Of interest: [How does Prolog answer this query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36464246/1243762)

Comment: Two people have the same hobby: `hobby(Person1, fishing), hobby(Person2, fishing)` for example. Or write a rule `same_hobby(P1, P2) :- hobby(P1, Hobby), hobby(P2, Hobby).` Note that if `P1` and `P2` have more than one hobby in common, this rule will succeed multiple times.

Comment: You said that you want to check if two people have the same hobby. But your example for `checkhobby` doesn't even use the `hobbies` data. It's a little confusing what you're really after here. This is sounding like you just need to go read the beginning chapters of a beginning Prolog book, or try a Prolog tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

finally, I did it

```
hobby(harry,music).
hobby(harry,running).
hobby(jocker,swimming).
hobby(jocker,movies).
hobby(jocker,art).
hobby(curl,running).
hobby(curl,art).
hobby(curl,movies).

same_hobby(P1,P2) :-
        dif(P1,P2),
        hobby(P1,H),
        hobby(P2,H).
```